# Spring Roo view - The drop down list is too big

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I have 2 entities: `Document (number, allocation)` and `Allocation (document, date)` with a ONE_TO_MANY relationship, one `Document` may have many `Allocations`.

In the form where you create a new `Allocation` there is a drop down list where you select a `Document` type item. This is list is too big, it has too many records. Is there another way to go about this? Maybe using a search box for `Document` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try changing `select.tagx` and add widgetAttrs like

```
autoComplete:false,  queryExpr: "*\${0}*"
```

for do search in the select box when anyone write in it.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. What I did was I set the following attributes: hasDownArrow : false, autoComplete:false. This was enough for me. Also do you know how to make the search results display only after I enter at least 3 characters in the select box?